# Returning a dispatch with promises in action creators of react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-actions

I have an **actionCreators** in my `/actions/authenticate.js`to seperate the logic of the **actions** dispatched by **redux** and the **component** of **react**.

Here is my `authenticate.js` which is my **actionCreators**

```
export function login(email, password) { // Fake authentication function
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch(loginRequest()); // dispatch a login request to update the state
        try {
            if (email.trim() === "test123@nomail.com" && password === "123456") { //If the email and password matches
                const session = { token: "abc1234", email: email, username: "test123" } // Create a fake token for authentication
                await AsyncStorage.setItem(DATA_SESSION, JSON.stringify(session)) // Stringinfy the session data and store it
                setTimeout(() => { // Add a delay for faking a asynchronous request
                    dispatch(loginSuccess(session)) // Dispatch a successful sign in after 1.5 seconds
                    return Promise.resolve()
                }, 1500)
            } else { // Otherwise display an error to the user
                setTimeout(() => { // Dispatch an error state
                    dispatch(loginFailed("Incorrect email or password"))
                }, 1500)
            }
        } catch (err) { // When something goes wrong
            console.log(err)
            dispatch(loginFailed("Something went wrong"));
            return Promise.reject()
        }
    };
} // login
```

Then I import that in my `someComponent.js` to import that **actionCreator** and bind it using [bindActionCreators](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators).

Something like this below:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import * as authActions from "../actions/authenticate";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
```

Then I connect that action to my **component** which is the `Login.js`

```
export default connect(
    state => ({ state: state.authenticate }),
    dispatch => ({
        actions: bindActionCreators(authActions, dispatch)
    })
)(Login);
```

So I can invoke the function in that actionCreator directly in the `Login.js`

Something like this below:

```
onPress={() => {                                 
   this.props.actions.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
}}
```

But what I want to happen is this function will **dispatch** an **redux action** and also return a **Promise** if that is possible?

Something like this:

```
onPress={() => {                                 
       this.props.actions.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
       .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthScreen'))
    }}
```

What I want to happen is when I try to sign in. Dispatch those asynchronous redux thunk actions and as well return a promise. If is been resolved or not so I can redirect or navigate to the correct screen.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first approach was mostly correct. `dispatch(thunkAction())` (or in your case `this.props.actions.login()` returns whatever `thunkAction()` returns, so it **does** return Promise in case it's `async`.

The problem is what that Promise resolves to, which is whatever you return from the `async` function. In your case, you don't wait for `setTimeout` and just return `void` regardless of whether credentials were correct or not.

So, in terms of async functions you'd need something like

```
export function login(email, password) { // Fake authentication function
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch(loginRequest()); // dispatch a login request to update the state
        try {
            if (email.trim() === "test123@nomail.com" && password === "123456") { //If the email and password matches
                const session = { token: "abc1234", email: email, username: "test123" } // Create a fake token for authentication
                await AsyncStorage.setItem(DATA_SESSION, JSON.stringify(session)) // Stringinfy the session data and store it
                // Add a delay for faking a asynchronous
                await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1500));
                dispatch(loginSuccess(session));
                return Promise.resolve(true);
            } else { // Otherwise display an error to the user
                await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1500));
                dispatch(loginFailed("Incorrect email or password"))
                return Promise.resolve(false);
            }
        } catch (err) { // When something goes wrong
            console.log(err)
            dispatch(loginFailed("Something went wrong"));
            return Promise.reject()
        }
    };
} // login
```

That way, your async function resolves to `true`/`false` that you can use in your component:

```
onPress={() => {                                 
       this.props.actions.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
       .then((login_succeeded) => this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthScreen'))
    }}
```

You can also `return dispatch(loginSuccess(session));` (as long as it's thunk that returns it and not the `setTimeout` handler), in which case `loginSuccess(session)` is what `.then()` will get in your `onPress` hook.

Comment: This one worked out! Thanks! I was also thinking if should I just past the `this.props.navigation.navigate` into the function and do the navigation logic there. But I think it was a bad idea. Is it?

Comment: You could either do that, or what you're doing now, or maybe [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html). Personally, I'd mostly aim at consistency (either handle navigation from your components, or actions) and otherwise do whatever is more convenient.

Comment: Ok. I think its cleaner. Btw Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly that i want.

Comment: Is it a good practice to pass dispatch to resolve or reject? The approach dispatches for storing and at the same time, you return the payload to the caller. I kinda don't like storing error messages in store as there is no need for it, hence I want it returned as reject. For example: `return Promise.reject( dispatch({type: 'ERROR', error: error}) );`. For resolve, depends on the case. I just like consistency across my action creators regardless if resolve/reject.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to redirect user to another page depending on `login` result, you should use [Redux Router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router), then in your `login` thunk you shoud dispatch an appropriate [navigation action](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-to-navigate-with-redux-action) which will redirect your user to the correct page.